# Cannot change region (locale) on MBP running OS X 10.9.2

Tags: macos, internationalization

I'm running OS X 10.9.2 on a MacBook Pro (Mid-2012) and cannot change its region (locale) via `System Preferences -> Language & Region`:

Changing it *ostensibly* works, but revisiting the preferences pane later shows the region reverted to its previous value.

In terms of what tools and apps report, the story is inconsistent:

- `defaults read -g AppleLocale` does show the NEW locale
- `locale`, by contrast, shows the PREVIOUS locale
- Similarly, Calendar.app shows holidays from the PREVIOUS locale

Thus, for the most part, the system behaves as if the region changes was ineffective - which is at least consistent with the preferences pane reverting to the previous value.

Here's what I've tried:

- Reset the NVRAM
- Repaired the disk with Disk Utility
- Booted into single-user mode and ran `fsck -yf`
- Cleared most caches with OnyX
- Checked the syslog for telltale entries

All to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you look in the Console at the Specific time stamp and for who is changing it back.

Comment: @Buscar웃: The only entries that changing the region seems to trigger are ones like `3/17/14 12:22:22.421 PM com.apple.time[181]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
` - and those also happen on machines where changing the region DOES work. Do you know what to look for specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there maybe an `AppleLocale` key in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist`? That would override the key in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Comment: That was indeed the problem - thank you. Any idea how the `AppleLocale` setting got in there? After deleting the `/ByHost/` version I noticed that a new incarnation reappeared later, though - fortunately - without an `AppleLocale` entry.